# GTIFProj4ToLatLong under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, geotiff

I use libgeotiff in my project. I want to convert pixel coordinates to geographic coordinates (latitude and longtitude). But GTIFProj4ToLatLong returns false. Target OS - Windows. I downloaded libraries from [here](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/pub/geotiff/libgeotiff/geotiff_win32_devkit.zip).

When I compile my project on Ubuntu using libgeotiff-dev from repository, everything works fine with the same code and the same tiff files.

I suppose some .csv or .lla files are missing when program runs on windows. Should I set some environment variables?

Another way I see is to build libgeotiff manually with mingw and msys. Can it help? It's complicated for me.

**Update:** I compiled libgeotiff manually using msys and mingw. Everything works now. Files from ftp.remotesensing.org seems to be built without Proj.4 support.

Answer (score 0):

To use this function, you should build libgeotiff with HAVE_LIBPROJ preprocessor flag. You'll also need libproj library for it